# Python: io redirect how to exclude return value from output content?

Tags: python, redirect, operating-system, output, system

E.g, I can use os.system to execute a shell command, like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls")
1p.py                  Tmytest1               getpip.py              src
1p.pyc                 a.out                  helloworld             tags
0
```

Seems the "0" is the return value of "system" function call, and python prints it out. Then I tried to redirect the system command output to a file like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> testlog=open('testlog.txt','w')
>>> os.dup2(testlog.fileno(),sys.stdout.fileno())
>>> print 'abc'
>>> print 'xyz'
>>> os.system("ls")
```

Then I cat "testlog.txt", I found the content contains last line of "0". This is not what I wanted, how to exclude the return value from being re-directed to output file?

Comment: Just do something like `a=os.system('ls')`, it will print the output of the command and not print the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a returned value, why not save it?

```
_ = os.system('ls')
```

After this, the value of `_` will be `0`, and that `0` won't be included in the output.